# Handling File System Events in OSX

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, events

So im using the EventStream to watch a folder for change. Now it all works fine and I can see a log call back when I alter files in the folder, but I cant seem to call my folderWatch, it gives the error "use of undeclared identifier 'self'". I can use this function everywhere else, just not in the fsEventsCallback. Any help would be appreciated!

```
   void fsEventsCallback(ConstFSEventStreamRef streamRef,
                      void *clientCallBackInfo,
                      size_t numEvents,
                      void *eventPaths,
                      const FSEventStreamEventFlags eventFlags[],
                      const FSEventStreamEventId eventIds[]){


    [self folderWatch];

    NSLog(@"2");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `fsEventsCallback` is a C function and not an Objective-C instance method, so `fsEventsCallback` does not know anything about `self`.

You can use the `info` field in the `FSEventStreamContext` to pass `self` to the callback function. The following example assumes that your class is called `Watcher`.

(If you don't use ARC, you can omit all the `__bridge` casts.)

```
- (void)folderWatch
{

}

void fsEventsCallback(ConstFSEventStreamRef streamRef,
                      void *info,
                      size_t numEvents,
                      void *eventPaths,
                      const FSEventStreamEventFlags eventFlags[],
                      const FSEventStreamEventId eventIds[])
{
    Watcher *watcher = (__bridge Watcher *)info;
    [watcher folderWatch];
}

- (void)startWatching
{
    FSEventStreamContext context;
    context.info = (__bridge void *)(self);
    context.version = 0;
    context.retain = NULL;
    context.release = NULL;
    context.copyDescription = NULL;

    NSArray *pathsToWatch = @[@"/path/to/watch"];

    self.eventStream = FSEventStreamCreate(NULL,
                                 &fsEventsCallback,
                                 &context,
                                 (__bridge CFArrayRef)(pathsToWatch),
                                 kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow,
                                 1.0,
                                 kFSEventStreamCreateFlagFileEvents
                                 );
}
```